# unable to change the color CSS

Tags: css

i am trying but unable to change the color of the text through CSS

here is my css code.

```
 .donfont1
 {
 margin: 0.8em 0 0.5em 0;    
 color:#00ff00;
 font-weight: 600;    
 font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif; 
 font-size: 16px;    
 line-height: 20px;    
 counter-increment: section-1;    
 counter-reset: section-2 section-3 section-4;
 position: relative; 
 text-align:center;
 } 

.leaf {
 list-style-type: none;
 background: url('images/feature.png') no-repeat top left;
 height: 46px;
 text-align:center;
 }
```

here is html code

```
<li class="leaf">
<p class="donfont1">
<a href=productdetails.php?url=<?php echo $friendlyurlget;?>>
<?php echo $propertytitle; ?>
</a>
</p>
</li>
```

please help me thanks

Comment: Show your HTML, give us a fiddle.

Comment: Most likely your rules are overwritten by styling set on the `a` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `text-decoration:none` to your anchor tag. By default, `color` isn't applied to the anchor tag and it stays blue.

Here's your modified HTML:

```
<li class="leaf">
<p class="donfont1">
<a style="text-decoration:none; color:#00ff00;" href=productdetails.php?url=<?php echo $friendlyurlget;?>>
<?php echo $propertytitle; ?>
</a>
</p>
</li>
```

If you want to repeatedly use it, incorporate it in your class.

Comment: Try using `<a class="donfont1">Text</a>` or try enclosing the whole thing in a `div`.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't change the font, then either the element has an inline style (in which case you will want to move the inline style to be defined in CSS, instead) or you have a specificity issue (in which case you need a selector with higher specificity). If you open your website in Chrome and use the Chrome developer tools, it should show you what styles have been applied to the element and where the styles are being replaced by other rules (which can help you track down the overriding rule if it is a specificity issue).

**Update**
Now that you've provided the example code, the issue is that the <a> tag has its own browser-default style. You should add a class to the <a> tag, and use that to specify your custom color (you may also want to add custom styles for the ":hover" and ":active" states, as well). For example:

```
 /* css */
 .product-details {
   color:#00ff00;
 }

 <!-- html -->
 <a class="product-details" href="productdetails.php?...">...</a>
```

Comment: I think you are wrong. He defined the color for the `p` element, but not for the contained `a` element, which is actually the only content/ child.

Comment: When I posted my answer, the OP had not yet posted his code. Agreed.

Answer (score 0):

If don't want to debug you can use color : color_code !important;

Comment: !important will increase the priority of css property

Comment: This works but is a really ugly solution, which I wouldn't recommend. (Though I've been guilty of it a few times, myself).

Comment: Yes you are correct use only in worst case when you don't have control of your inline css

Answer (score 0):

You define the text color for text inside your `p` element. Actually the only content of your `p` element is a link `a` element as child.

Link elements have a default color defined by the browser's (user agent) stylesheet.

So you have to define the colors for `elements` e.g. like this:

```
a {
  color: #0F0;
  text-decoration: none; /* if you do not want your links to be underlined */
}

a:visited {
  color: #FF0;
}

a:hover {
  color: #FFF;
}

a:active {
  color: #0FF;
}
```

Notive the different pseudo-classes for `a` elements. The order in your CSS is important.

BTW: I think you also have a mistake in your HTML code!
Should be:

```
<a href="productdetails.php?url=<?php echo $friendlyurlget;?>" <?php echo $propertytitle; ?>>
```